# Exercises on the subject Theory of Quantum Information

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer

I have recently started to study quantum information theory on Nielsen and Chuang book, but in order to understand the theory better I need to solve more problems, there are in this book. Can you recommend a book or a book of exercises, where there will be problems on the topics from this book?

Comment: You could try here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One textbook I can recommend is "Quantum Computer Science: An Introduction" by the inestimable N. David Mermin.